# How do I translate “exercise” to French? Is “exercice” correct?

Tags: vocabulaire, sport

Exact question as above. When I say “exercise” it is “exercise” in the sense of physical activity for example, running, badminton, swimming, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As noun, "exercice" is correct. We can also use "entrainement" (à la course, au badmington, etc.) which is "training" in English.

An "exercice" can be considered as a specific (specialized) part of the (more general) training. Also an "entrainement" is a set of "exercices".

So the translation to use ("exercice" or "entrainement") is dependent on the context.

As verb, "s'exercer" ou "s'entrainer".

Comment: There is also "faire de l'exercice" which is more generally "to do sport so you stay fit". Not sure if the English "to do some exercise" is equivalent or not.

Comment: @AnneAunyme based on your translation of the french, I'd say "to exercise" is the English equivalent, frequently understood from context to mean staying in shape

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble: I confirm it is the same meaning, then.